# Java swing rendering problem card deck black images

Tags: java, swing, canvas, render, graphics2d

I have a little problem displaying certain card images, **7,8,9,10, A spades and clubs.**
As you can see in the image numbers on those cards look thicker. There is no scaling.
They are `Graphics2D` objects and I tried with a different combination `setRenderingHint` but everything gives me the same look of numbered black cards.
[Black card problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJkKt.png)

Comment: Where are the images of the cards coming from?  Rendering hints do not affect the drawing of images.  Rendering hints only affect drawing with Graphics and Graphics2D methods.

Comment: Images are loaded to BufferedImage

Comment: You have two choices.  Either get better card images or draw the cards yourself using the Graphics2D drawString and drawShape methods.